# Spark Data Frame operation time grows dramatically when calling in sequential order

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying some pyspark dataframe operations because of multi core advantages of pyspark according to pandas. Firstly I convert pandas data frame to pyspark data frame. I give as a parameter x_df_sp pyspark dataframe with size (1009224, 232).

```
depth = 6 #3

def append_history_spark(x_df_sp, field):
    for i in range(1, depth+1):
       x_df_sp = x_df_sp.withColumn("t-%d-duration" % (i), x_df_sp["DURATION"] - i)
       x_df_sp = x_df_sp.join(x_df_sp["DURATION", "PARTY_ID", field]
                           .withColumnRenamed(field, "RIGHT_" + field)
                           .withColumnRenamed("PARTY_ID", "RIGHT_PARTY_ID") 
                           .withColumnRenamed("DURATION", "RIGHT_DURATION"),
                        (col('PARTY_ID') == col('RIGHT_PARTY_ID')) &
                        (col("t-%d-duration" % (i)) == col('RIGHT_DURATION'))
                           ,'left')
       cols = ["RIGHT_PARTY_ID", "RIGHT_DURATION", "t-%d-duration" % (i), "DURATION_y"]
       x_df_sp = x_df_sp.drop(*cols)
       x_df_sp = x_df_sp.withColumnRenamed("RIGHT_%s" % (field), "%s_T%d" % (field, i))

    return x_df_sp
```

Then I call the method in this way. First line is executed in 1-2 seconds. Second line takes 40-50 seconds. Then its growing dramatically. Actually I do not understand problem with calling function in sequencial way. Is there any idea or suggestion ?

```
df_sp = append_history_spark(df_sp, 'Feature1x')
df_sp = append_history_spark(df_sp, 'Feature2x')
df_sp = append_history_spark(df_sp, 'Feature3x')
df_sp = append_history_spark(df_sp, 'Feature4x')
df_sp = append_history_spark(df_sp, 'Feature5x') 
df_sp = append_history_spark(df_sp, 'Feature6x') 
df_sp = append_history_spark(df_sp, 'Feature7x')
```

Comment: you can call `.cache()` for the intermediate dataframes, but remember to `.unpersist()` once they are no longer needed

Comment: I tried to call .cache() for all intermadiate dataframes, after each call I call .unpersist() for old one. But situation is still same.